# Problem installing Delphi 10.4 Android SDK

Tags: android, delphi, sdk

I have done an install of Delphi 10.4 Sydney on a machine with a clean Windows 10,
accepting all the defaults.
Yet the Android SDK clearly is not installed properly.

At a minimum
Missing Directories: \android-29 & \29.0.3

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-21.0.37889.9797\platforms\android-29

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-21.0.37889.9797\build-tools\29.0.3

I have reinstalled the SDK but no change.

Can anyone help with the SDK install.

Comment: How did you reinstall the SDK? Did you use the Additional Options tabsheet on the Platform Manager?

Comment: This would be a question more suitable to ask at Idera support, as it's related to your Delphi installation.

Comment: Reinstall: on Compile Delphi will notify that the SDK is not installed and offer to install through the platform manager.
I have tried to contact Embarcadero. / Idera Support. nothing back yet.
if  they advise the issue I will post here.
Since this was an install on a brand new machine, i was interested to know if others have encountered this problem and found a solution.

Comment: This problem has been there for a while and not yet been fixed. I suggest you use the Additional Options tabsheet on the Platform Manger to install the SDK.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I found.
The problem results from not selecting the option to also install AdoptOpenJDK.
(I had the Oracle version installed)
Once I Uninstalled Delphi removed the Oracle JDK, and reinstalled including AdoptOpenJDK the Automatic install of the Android SDK worked.

Answer (score 1):

You must install the platforms and other requirements separately. Use SDKManager.exe in SDK folder to install them.
You can select which package you want to download by selecting the checkbox and then click Install to install those packages. By default SDK Manager keeps it up to date with latest APIs and other packages.

See this source for more information:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sdk_manager.htm

Note that you can use different platforms and build-tools but sometimes this is not possible.

Comment: If OP hasn't been able to install the tools, the the SDK manager will be absent. Downloading and installing the SDK/NDK from scratch - and then configuring the IDE to use it, is not a trivial task.

Comment: I tried installing the SDK manually, it is as mentioned above not trivial and I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I installed RAD Studio Enterprise, only Delphi (all platforms), not C++.  I also installed:

- Samples
- Help
- AdoptOpenJDK
- Android SDK 25.2.5 - NDK r21

In Delphi, there were warning icons on the following:

```
Tools | Options | Deployment | SDK Manager | Android SDK ... | Properties
* SDK  - ZipAlign location
* SDK  - Adb location
* SDK  - Aapt location
* SDK  - SDK API-Level location
* Java - KeyTool location
* Java - Jarsigner location
```

To fix the Java issues, use `Tools | Manage Platforms | Additional Options` to remove both AdoptOpenJDK and the Android SDK.  Then used it again to install both.

To fix the SDK issues, browse to the folder where the Android SDK was installed (look at `SDK - SDK base path` under the `SDK Manager` for Android).  For me the path is:

`c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-21.0.40680.4203`

Run `SDK Manager.exe` to launch the `Android SDK Manager` application.  For me, 16 packages were pre-selected, including rev 29 tools (which is the path that was in `SDK API-Level location`).  The Google Play options under Android R wouldn't install because their download size didn't match the expected download size.  So I removed Android R support.  The others worked just fine.

Note: There is a `SDK Readme.txt` in the same folder that has some useful information.  The readme mentions a command you can run from a command prompt (`tools\android.bat update sdk --no-ui`), which I ran.  That installed support for several other versions of Android.  Be sure to run it from the SDK folder, not the tools sub-folder.

Everything works now.

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped me. I just want to add that in my case my computer was connected to the Internet through an http-proxy, and the console application that the RAD studio launches to install SDK Tools does not take into account the system setting of the proxy and cannot download the necessary packages. But SDK Manager have GUI, so I can set proxy settings (menu Tools - Options)

Answer (score 0):

**Concise Answer**:

I have encountered this problem in 10.4 and 11 too. The solution in a nutshell is `use manual install of the sdk to a different folder and point to this in the option>deployment>sdk manager paths. Repeat the same with NDK. JDK(oracle or adopt) can be installed afterwards too and pointed to similarly.` I follwed this [Jim McKeeth article](http://delphi.org/2019/06/manually-installing-android-sdk-ndk-and-java-for-firemonkey-development/) to download and use the CLI sdk manager as the gui manager doesn't exist anymore. Thankfully I was testing in a VM. First and foremost make sure you are installing the IDE to an x64 OS (There's no way around it). Be very careful with the `apksigner.jar` path input in the IDE since it is located in the nearby lib folder. It isn't the apksigner.bat in bin folder! Otherwise you get corrupt jar file error in the final stages of apk signing/aligning before deployement.

**Expanded Answer**:

Doesn't matter what state your SDK, NDK or JDK is after the RAD Studio Installer finishes, you can always add new SDK/delete SDK/edit these three in this dialog:
[image]

**A**:
From that linked article to set up the SDK, I 'added new' sdk in the dialog and deleted the previous two defaults (android 32 is obsolete anyway):

1. download the seed content(commandlinetools-win-8512546_latest) from android.google to a new folder - call it AndroidSDK.
2. Now instruct the CLI SDK Manager(by navigating up to it) to fulfill/download the full SDK:
   `sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.2" "extras;google;usb_driver" "platforms;android-31" "tools" "platform-tools" --sdk_root="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\AndroidSDK"`These version numbers I get from what is supported by my current RAD Studio (11 Alexandria in my case). Also the last path is the arbitrary path which I called AndroidSDK before (container of the seed folder or equivalently couple of levels up than the CLI sdkmanager). Update the SDK paths in the above dialog while keeping in mind the `apksigner.jar` thing i told previously.

**B**: NDK is a straight-up download from android.google again which I extract to an arbitrary folder `android-ndk-r21e`. Update the same in the above dialog.

**C**: I used one of the latest jdk from oracle because the version differences can cause apk signing error. After ensuring it was in the windows path at the top, i updated the same in the above dialog.